# How to set Jhtmlarea editor to blank or empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jhtmlarea

I've a `textarea` and have implemented `jHtmlArea` Editor jquery plugin. And when click on reset button. I need to set it to empty or blank.

HTML is as below

```
  <textarea cols="170" id="area4" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I tried, But it didn't work.

```
  $('#area4').htmlarea('html', '');
```

Any other suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made it with the help of this code. just used an extra white space ;) and worked smooth for me

```
  $('#area4').htmlarea("html", "  ");
```

Answer (score 3):

yep i just got this to work:

```
$('#textarea-content').htmlarea('html',' ');
```

but this doesn't work

```
$('#textarea-content').htmlarea('html','');
```

ok these seems to be best

```
$('#textarea-content').htmlarea('html','\n');
```

or

```
$('#textarea-content').htmlarea('html','\b');
```

they leave no space at the start

on this page http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/jhtmlarea.html

Comment: http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modify%20Editor%20Programatically%20using%20JavaScript

Comment: yea im getting very frustrated lol i see the issue the textarea does empty but the iframe doesnt update

Comment: this should do it $('#txtDefaultHtmlArea').html('').htmlarea(); but it doesn't either

Comment: same issue was with me too..i seeked into html and set body to empty in iframe..:P but didn't work..